# Reasons to save a .webp image with the extension .jpg?

Tags: image-processing, prestashop, jpeg, file-extension, webp

Would there be any reason or benefits to save a .webp image with the extension .jpg?

Background for my question:

In the module ETS Super Speed for Prestashop
(https://addons.prestashop.com/en/website-performance/44977-super-speed-incredibly-fast-gtmetrix-optimization.html)
you can optimize the uploaded images.
This feature is found in the demo under "Image optimization" in the menu.

When selecting "Google Webp image optimizer" in the setting "Image optimization method", you'll get the following option:
"Change file extension to .webp for product images when converting?"
This setting is disabled by default. So by default it will save the .webp images with .jpg extension.

The optimization method "Google Webp image optimizer" is made by WebP Convert, https://github.com/rosell-dk/webp-convert.

Comment: there would be no no benefit because it's *wrong*. -- a possible reason is that whoever did that has no idea what they're doing. -- the *extension* isn't supposed to be *changed*. **the file extension always has to reflect the file format.** if they generate WebP, the extension as to be .webp. if they generate JPEG, the extension should be .jpg or .jpeg -- perhaps you should talk to their technical support and ask them to explain what they're doing there.

Comment: I guess this is because jpg/png extension is checked in many part of Prestashop as the unique valid for images and it's also denied in native htaccess (see https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/10356 ) , so third party developed had to "invent" this solution.

Comment: "you can optimize the uploaded images". For already uploaded images? I guess it's for SEO, so that the image name stays the same.